# Can I hide scroll bars but keep overflow on?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

I want to make a custom horizontal scrollbar so that all OSs render it the same, no ugly windows scrollbars.

I know how to make one via JS using some division with scroll top, but I need to hide the default scroll bars, but leave overflow on so I can still detect the onscroll event (so gestures on OSX touchpad, mousewheeel, etc. are all handled for me and trigger the onscroll callback).

Ideas?

Comment: Touchpads may be a problem, but you can listen for the mousewheel event instead of the scroll event to make the element scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manage all by yourself.
iOS devices doesn't trigger scroll events like desktop browser. You have scroll event only at the end of the touch.
If you want track all the scrolling sequence, you have to track the touchstart/touchmove/touchend (and touchcancel).

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these examples: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Not sure if the onscroll event is triggered, never tried it. If not, the mousewheel plugin included probably gives you some callbacks to handle what you want...

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to pull in 5+ files to accomplish this...but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:hidden` should do what you want; it can still be programmatically scrolled.

Comment: No onScroll event though, so I'd have to connect to mousewheel events, touchpad events, drag events, etc. I think I'll just float divs on the left and right of the div I'm attempting to scroll and as the mouse moves over them, scroll respectively.

Comment: That's not accessible to non-mouse users.  You could also try `overflow:scroll` plus manual styling of the scroll bars themselves, which is not entirely standardized but may well work enough for this situation.  Alternatively, just give up and embrace platform diversity.